# sitefinity Mvc Widget not redirecting

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

I am using the code below on my sitefinity mvc widget to redirect to the index method with a conrtoller and getting 404 error any ideas.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult editSubjectDetails(eLearningSubjectModel model)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "PRManagerController");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution

login into sitefinity click administartion> settings>advantced>pages and tick EnableBackwardCompatabilityForPagesUrls and the code that i have added works fine.

Comment: That's a much better solution, providing this setting doesn't have any other consequences,

Comment: this setting was created by sitefinity to aid in redirecting MVC widgets.

Answer (score 1):

redirect to action changes the url . if you have to call the method then call the page that are using your mvc widget